# Digital Timer Help to stop timer and user input

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to JAVA , i was ask to design this digital timer. I have a problem with stoping a timer. When the user enters values for minutes and seconds and  presses the Pause Timer button it should stop the timer and display the numbers, my timer look like this:

```
 private void btStartTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                btAddOneActionPerformed(evt);


            }
        });
tm.start();
```

How do i stop the timer when the user presses the pause button?

![Timer GUI][1]

All the help will be very appreciated.

Comment: That has to be one of the worst GUI layouts I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Swing `Timer` has a [`start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#start--) and [`stop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop--) method which you can use.

```
final Timer timer = ...;
timer.start();
...
JButton button = ... ;
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    timer.stop();
  }
});
```